# Peano (Dedekind) categoricity

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, peano-arithmetic

What is the smallest fragment of second order logic such that $Th(\mathbb{N})$ in that logic is categorical (only one model, namely natural numbers, up to isomorphism). For example, can we do this in FO+TC (transitive closure). The second order Peano Axioms have this property while the first order doesn't. Can we do it less than full second order?

Comment: The paper "Reverse mathematics and Peano categoricity" by Simpson and Yokoama may be related to you question. A preprint is available at http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/papers/rmpc.pdf .

Comment: It is enough to add the quantifier $\forall^\infty x$ meaning for all but finitely many.

Comment: FO+TC is certainly enough: you can express that every element is accessible from 0 by the transitive closure of the successor relation.